# How many prime numbers we need?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

If we have some not prime number $n > 1$ we always can make prime factorization. For this operation we need $m$ prime numbers.

Is there any way to prove that for given $n$ we can use no more then $m$ first prime numbers?

P.S.
For example to cache first $m$ prime numbers in RAM.

Comment: Well, yes, a first (rough) estimate is that for $n$ we need at most $2\sqrt n$ primes.

Comment: If you want to use trial division for prime factorization, you have to go to the primes upto $\sqrt{n}$ in the worst case. So, for large numbers, trial division is slow and at some point, unfeasible.

Comment: The question is formulated in a very unclear manner. The way you phrased it sounds like the following: If $n=3^{101}$ then its prime factorization needs only a single prime, namely $p=3$. Therefore in this case $m=1$. At least that was my first interpretation. My second guess was that you are asking about the number of prime factors, which for the above $n$ would be $m=101$. A general bound being $m\le \log_2n$. Judging from the answer you mean something else entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the next higher perfect square and then you need to check only till the greatest prime less than the square root of the nearest greater perfect square you found.

For ex. if the number you want to check is $623$. The next higher perfect square is $625$; $\sqrt {625} = 25$. The greatest prime number less than $25$ is $23$. So to check if $623$ is prime it is enough to check till $23$.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In other words, the max number of primes is $\le \pi(\lceil \sqrt{n}\,\rceil)$. The bound is reached e.g. for $n=6$.

Comment: Simple and beautiful. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't it rather $\le 2\cdot\pi(\lceil\sqrt n\rceil)$? Because we can also have prime divisors greater than $\sqrt n$.

Comment: The original question is hard to understand.  At first I thought it was how *many* factors were possible, but then it seems to be the cardinality of the set of primes necessary for trial division.  In other words, "how many primes are needed to perform a trial division primality test?" which Jackson's answer nicely works out and gammatester clarifies.  I infer that Berci is inferring the question is asking how many primes are possible results of a factorization.

Answer (score 0):

We know if $n$ is less than the primorial number $p_{x}\#!$ then $m$ is less than $x$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It depends how you interpret '$m$ prime numbers'. If we write out the unique factorisation of a number $n$, and use $m$ prime numbers, then i have provided the correct answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see your point. How is the condition with primorial related to the question?

Comment: Q. "Is there any way to prove that for a given $n$ we can use no more then $m$ first prime numbers?" A. Yes, if we know $n$ is less than $p_{x}\#!$ then we know $m$ is less than $x$ by comparison of unique prime factorisations. The relation is by the concept of natural numbers.

Comment: @user2097 can you explain where "Make prime factorisation" is defined.

Comment: I don't know. Actually, I don't think the question is well-posed either...

Comment: Well actually the other answer was what he wanted. Maybe somebody can point out the ambiguity for when his future questions become deeper.

Comment: Perhaps if you would answer with more detail than a one-liner permits, the ambiguity in the question could be pointed out (and ambiguity in your answer removed).